# Can I only deploy the server side of my react native app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, heroku

I have a react native app that I'm building using expo. For the backend, I am using node.js and Express.
My app hierarchy is such that I have a frontend folder and a backend (server) folder. For example,

```
Root
|
 |Frontend
  |Various screens & associated files 
 |Server
  |Routes & other files
```

For my project, is it possible to just host the backend and not the rest of the app? Such that when I fetch data in the frontend using HTTP requests, instead of routing through localhost (http: //RandomIP:PORT/route) I would use the heroku address as the routing address. I would also host the SQL database along with it.

I tried to follow along with the Heroku documentation, but it seemed like that was for hosting the entirety of the app / web apps instead of mobile, and I ran into constant errors.

Comment: Is this really related to the SQL _language_?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point out that, unlike web pages, mobile apps cannot be hosted on the server and fetched on-demand. In other words, do not try to upload your react-native code to Heroku instead just upload your backend only and then make HTTP requests through the URL provided by Heroku after you have deployed your code.

Therefore go into your backend codebase, initialize a git repository and just deploy that Heroku. Also, you will need to host your SQL database on another service such as Google's [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql) or Amazons [AWS Database Services](https://aws.amazon.com/free/database).